# How to split a txt into custom paragraphs (and then insert them into excel columns)?

Tags: python, split, nlp, readlines

I need to retrieve each section of the text. These sections are identifiable because they start with the words 'First','Second','Third' and so on. Then I need to insert each section in a different column in excel. For example the text reads:

First blablablabla. Then blablabla.
Last blabla.

Second blabla. Then blabla. Last blabla.

Third blabla. also blabla. Fourth bla.

I know this code is entirely wrong but it's what I have tried so far:

```
with open("adress","r", encoding="utf8") as f:
  lines = f.readlines()

  for i in lines:
    words= i.split('\n\n')
    print(words)

    for i in words:
        print(i,i=='First')
```

Comment: Can you give a clearer representation of your text structure? Also what do you mean by 'retrieve' a section exactly? Are you willing to organize chunks of text in a list or something? Because it looks like you're just printing stuff.

Comment: yeah I would like to have every paragraph as an object that I can manipulate later! (thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will split your text correctly:

```python
with open("address","r", encoding="utf8") as file:
    sections = file.read()

    sections = sections.split('\n\n')
    for section in sections:
        print(section)
```

You can't split string by two newlines when you earlier split it by newline.

Comment: thank you so much! could you just help me w one last question... how do I like manipulate each section? For example if I wanted to add an index or an attribute to each paragraph?

Comment: @AnaAlfaroPizaña You can make for example: 
for section_id, section in enumerate(sections):
        print(f"{section_id + 1}. {section}")
Instead of:
    for section in sections:
        print(section)